# Flutter - Firebase Firestore as a service

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stream

In Flutter, I want to create a class that serves as a **service to Firebase Firestore DB**.
So that instead of listening to a document change **directly** from my controller / model like so:

```
StreamSubscription<DocumentSnapshot> listener = FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('products')
  .doc(productId)
  .snapshots()
  .listen(_onProductUpdate);
```

I'll have a method in my service, that will delegate that stream, like so:

```
Stream<Product> listenToProduct(String productId) {
  return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products')
    .doc(productId)
    .snapshots()
    .map((snapshot) => Product.fromJson(snapshot.data()!));
}
```

And my controller / model will use it like so:

```
GetIt.I<FirestoreService>()
    .listenToProduct(productId)
    .listen(_onProductUpdate);
```

My only issue is that I don't know how to cancel the subscription listener in the second case.
I mean, when listening directly to Firestore, I can use:

```
listener.cancel();
```

How do I achieve this using my Firestore service?

Comment: You may want to tag this with the language you're using, which is unclear at this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable of `static StreamSubscription? subscription;` and reference the **listen** to that variable, `subscription = reference.onValue.listen...` and then you can use

```
if (subscription != null) {
      subscription!.cancel();
    }
```

to cancel it